# Tensor Product of irreducible modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb C$ algebra. Let $S$ be an irreducible $A$ module?

Then what $ S \otimes_A Hom_A(S,S)$? Is it equal to S? I know that $S \otimes_{\mathbb C} Hom_A(S,S)$ is isomorphic to $S$ as a $\mathbb C$ vector space but what is $ S \otimes_A Hom_A(S,S)$?

Comment: Your claim about the tensor product over $\mathbb{C}$ is false (if you intended a natural isomorphism); for example, take $A = \mathbb{C}(x), S = A$. You need more hypotheses for Schur's lemma to hold at this level of generality.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $S \otimes_A Hom_A(S,S)$ doesn't make sense, because if $S$ is an irreducible right $A$-module, there is usually not any natural left $A$-module structure on $Hom_A(S,S)$.  For instance, if $A=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ for some $n>1$ and $S=\mathbb{C}^n$, then $Hom_A(S,S)=\mathbb{C}$ cannot be made into an $A$-module (in any way compatible with the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space structure).